# Flutter, How to make a widget under the navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I implemented bottom navigator inside Scaffold() using

```
bottomNavigationBar : BottomNavigationBar()
```

and then I realized that I don`t know the way

how to add Admob(or Widget(Container)) under the bottom navigator bar

and also bottomSheet makes the widget appear above the bottom navigation bar

is there any solution for this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think adding one more scaffold to scaffold can help you to achieve it easily.

checkout below minimal code which simulates the same.

```
Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      child: Text("second"),
    ),
    body: Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        child: Text("first"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text("press"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: wow, great. are there any adverse side effects from doing this?

Comment: 1 of the best solutions to this. Thanks man